# Remote Powershell run interactive batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-remoting

This is probably a question with a binary answer.

I have a series of batch files on a server. They all require user input in some way, either via CHOICE or SET.

I would like to run these remotely from my desktop, using powershell.

Is this possible? My tests so far show the batch scripts running, but they skip past any user input.

If the above is not possible, is anyone able to point me to a resource that has information on a powershell implementation of accepting user inputs remotely?

The scripts need to stay in a central location, so all the users should have is a single PS script on their desktop that runs a PS script on the server that is responsible for requesting and handling user input.

Cheers

EDIT:

I tried Invoke-Command and Enter-pssession already, neither work. I get the following error message:

```
.\MultiScript.bat :
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteExeption
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

ERROR: The file is either empty or does not contain the valid choices.
```

Here is a code excerpt:

```
CHOICE /C 123456789 /M "Enter your choice:"

IF ERRORLEVEL 9 call %installdir%\stream\check1 %input% & GOTO main
...etc
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 call %installdir%\single\getlogs %input% & GOTO main
```

On my powershell terminal it shows that it is automatically selecting option 9 above to run another script. In the following script, and ID is requested from the user, and I can see there is automatically the female gender symbol (char[9792]) given as input.

The issue really seems to be Powershell does not understand the CHOICE or SET keywords and just skips past them, or gives weird inputs.

Comment: Are you running the powershell on your desktop to your desktop and trying to run files located on a server? OR are you trying to run this from your desktop to another desktop?

Comment: I usually use `PSEXEC` to do something like that. But I would assume `Powershell` has some functionality like that.

Comment: I'm running powershell on my desktop, connecting to a server via the Invoke-command/enter-pssession, to run scripts located on the server.
The scripts must stay on the server, but if I can run them from powershell on my desktop, it saves having to RDP and then run them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the commands remotely. To do this you can use this as an example

```
Invoke-command -computername SERVERhostname -sessionoption (new-pssessionoption -nomachineprofule) -scriptblock {cmd.exe /c "c:/batchfile.bat -option"}
```

Replace SERVERhostname appropriately.

Unless you're saying it asks questions. Then you can remote into the server.

```
Enter-pssession
```

will do as you need

Comment: I tried both of those methods, neither allows me to enter anything. Actually it seems to run the last choice (9) in the code above, then requests information using SET, and enters a blank value.